# MCP3008 and Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: mcp3008

Can I use MCP3008 to input analog signals to Raspberry Pi Zero? If not, Which is the cheapest version of Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. There's no difference in the GPIO/SPI capabilities of any Pi models.

Here's a guide which includes wiring, enabling hardware SPI and reading analog input signals with Python (though you can use anything - this is just the simplest way): https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing/15

Also see the gpiozero docs on MCP3008: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_spi.html#gpiozero.MCP3008