# How to make lilypad temperature sensor work with raspberry pi zero?

Tags: gpio, gpiozero, mcp3008

I discovered a lilypad sensor thought of connecting it with raspberry pi zero to measure living room temperature. But lilypad sensor is  analog input and pi doesn’t have analog pin.

How can i make this working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to buy an ADC (Analogue to Digital Converter) such as the popular MCP3008.

You connect the Lilypad output to the ADC and the ADC to the Pi.  The MCP3008, for example, uses the Pi's SPI GPIO.

You then write a program to read the data from the ADC.  Python is a popular choice and there are hundreds of examples on-line.

Comment: What is the pinout for mcp3008 with pi zero that would be helpful

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz First google hit for pi zero mcp3008 is https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93167/mcp3008-and-raspberry-pi-zero